# Merge two consecutive values to one double value in one array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, double

how i can do following array conversion in php?

```
// turn
array ('1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd');

// into
array ('1,a', '2,b', '3,c', '4,d');
```

Comment: easy with one of several types of loops, give it a go

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  to learn more about how to properly ask questions here.  For starters,  stackoverflow isnt a coding service -- for that you'll want to search elsewhere. Stackoverflow is actually a place where you submit your code which isnt working correctly, and then the community helps out by recommending ways to fix it etc etc.  Read though http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  as its full of useful information

Comment: @mike510a horse has bolted he has 2 answerers already, i dont expect he will ignore them and try something himself

Comment: @nogad I just copy/pasted that little snippet anyways

Answer (score 1):

You can easily to that with [array_chunk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
$original = array ('1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd');

$new_array = array();
foreach(array_chunk($original, 2) as $values) {
    $new_array[] = implode(',', $values);
}

var_dump($new_array );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm bored:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return implode(',', $v); },
                   array_chunk($array, 2));
```

- Chunk the array into child arrays of 2 values
- Map each chunk into a function that implodes the values

Answer (score -2):

I am using JavaScript but same logic applies for php too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = ['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c', '4', 'd'];

    var nlist = [];

    for(i=0; i<list.length-1; i+=2)
        nlist.push("'"+list[i]+","+list[i+1]+"'");

    alert(nlist[0]); //'1,a'
    alert(nlist); //'1,a', '2,b', '3,c', '4,d'
</script>
```

Comment: question was not tagged wth JS

Comment: what ever language you may use sometimes logic is more important than the syntax.

Comment: if every language had the same function set that would be true, but they dont.